# spark-submit err (yarn-cluster full ditributed mode)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I use spark yarn-cluster mode.

I created my dependency jar(`kAnonymity_maven-jar-with-dependencies.jar`) using `maven-dskipTests clean package` command using maven.

and my command is

```
spark-submit --class com.kAnonymity_maven.kAnonymity_spark 
--master yarn 
--deploy-mode cluster 
--driver-memory 12g
--executor-memory 12g
--executor-cores 8  
--jars hdfs:///jars/kAnonymity_maven-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
kAnonymity_maven-jar-with-dependencies.jar 10
```

and `kAnonymity_maven-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is located in  `hdfs:///jars`

and my spark setting is

```
spark.yarn.archive  hdfs:///home/hp/jar/spark-libs.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath hdfs:///jars
spark.executor.extraClassPath  hdfs:///jars
```

I get this error when I use rdd.collect () or rdd.first () in my spark code.

```
   User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 47, slave2, executor 2): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.kAnonymity_maven.kAnonymity_spark
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.hasStaticInitializer(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1887)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:263)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:261)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:260)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:682)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1883)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1358)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1331)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1372)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1371)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.first(JavaPairRDD.scala:221)
at com.kAnonymity_maven.kAnonymity_spark.performGeneralization(kAnonymity_spark.java:500)
at com.kAnonymity_maven.kAnonymity_spark.performAnonymity(kAnonymity_spark.java:529)
at com.kAnonymity_maven.kAnonymity_spark.run(kAnonymity_spark.java:601)
at com.kAnonymity_maven.kAnonymity_spark.main(kAnonymity_spark.java:640)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:706)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.kAnonymity_maven.kAnonymity_spark
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.hasStaticInitializer(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1887)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:263)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:261)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:260)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:682)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1883)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But if I do not use the rdd.collect () or rdd.first () command, the code will run fine.

What errors are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting class initialisation error. Please check in - - class you are giving full package name with the class name. I don’t see any issues with the collect or first. I suppose any action you will get error. Apart from that try printing some value in console and check if it’s working and revert with the details. I will analyse and keep you posted